# Mapping the inital numbers to all of letters

Tags: c, numbers, mapping, assign, letters

[On this Question they are asking assign the numbers to the letters][1]

Question:

Suppose that we assign the score 1 to character A, 2 to B, and
26 to Z by repeating the same rule. With the scores mapped by this rule, the sum of scores for
“Luck’ is 47 (12 + 21 + 3 + 11), “Knowledge” is 96, “Hardwork” is 98, and “Attitude” is 100.
Complete the following program which computes for an arbitrary string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
char str[1000];
int i, score = 0;
scanf("%s", str);
for (i = 0; ______; ___) 
{ 
int ch = str[i];
if (______________________) {
score += ____________;
}
else if (______________________) {
score += ____________;
}
}
printf("%d\n", score);
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Click on the link at the top side of topic.

Comment: @CherubimAnand i have an exam for morning and it's 2:18 am now it's been almost 13 hours i'm studying,Please be humble and generous before judge someone.Thanks sir

Comment: @CherubimAnand thanks for feedback.

Comment: To determine the size of the string(the loop) use sizeof(string)/sizeof(int); and for the conditionals you can use cast a char as an int like so: (int) string[i]

Answer (score 1):

The key insight for this question is that a char is actually an 8-bit number. For instance, 'a' is 97 in decimal, 'z' is 122, 'A' is 65, and 'Z' is 90:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Code_chart

All the alphabet characters are represented sequentially. Because a char is actually a number, you can use it in an arithmetic expression, like so:

```
 int num = 'd' - 'a'; //num is now (100 - 97), which is 3.
```

This should be enough information to figure out what they want you to do in that problem.

Comment: I should add that ASCII only uses 7 bits. Nonetheless, the char datatype is 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this efficiently by using only two conditionals like so:

```
if (string[i]>='a' && string[i]<='z') {
    Score += (int) string[i] - (int) 'a' + 1;
}
```

**Edit: The int casts are not needed but I put them there so you can tell that the chars are being used as ints**

For the second conditional, you can do the same in upper case. 
This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](http://ascii.cl/) table. ASCII values for `A-Z` ranges from `65-90` and for `a-z` ranges from `97-122`. Hence, to convert a character into a number, you can use:

for UPPER CASE: `ch - 64` or `ch - 'A' + 1`
for lower case: `ch - 96` or `ch - 'a' + 1`

which will map `A` to `1`, `B` to `2` ... so on
and `a` to `1`, `b` to `2` ... so on

as shown in the below program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char str[1000];
    int i, score = 0;


    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    printf("You entered: %s\n", str);


    for( i=0; str[i] != '\0' ; i++ ) {

        int ch = str[i];
        int num;

        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <='Z'){
            num = ch -'A' + 1;
            // num = ch - 64;
        }

        else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
            num = ch -'a' + 1;
            // num = ch - 96;
        }

        score += num;
    }

    printf("Score: %d\n", score);
}
```